# Spiralling cycles surrounding zeros

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

The following came up, as a vague idea, in dialogue with a bright, female, 20 year old student of mine. It is a bit vague, but it seems that conjecture 1 is not present in the literature, which seems rather odd. 2 and 3 are of course well known, 2 first conjectured by Littlewood, and 3 by Lindelöf, and obviously the Lehmer issue is adjacent.

**Core idea:** Within the $\zeta(s)$ critical strip, as we encircle a zero by spiraling around it drawing infinitesimally small circles that surround it, the topology inside the short intervals forces the spiral's cycle to be bounded by 1. This can be shown using Jacobi elliptic theta functions to code the $\Xi(z)$  function.

**Conjecture 1 (Broken symmetry in the critical strip)**

For the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, written as

$\zeta(s) - f(s) - i g(s) = 0$,

where $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ are harmonic functions, within the critical strip, if $\sigma$ tends to the real part of all the non-trivial zeros in, or to the right, of the critical line, and $t$ tends to infinity, the difference

$$|f(s)| - |g(s)|$$

tends to zero. At around $t=14.2$, and $t=48$,  the difference is already quite delicate, close to $0.08$ and $0.01$, respectively. This makes the zero near 48 difficult to see, a phenomenon that should make it impossible to detect certain zeros as t grows.

**Conjecture 2 (Vanishing ordinate differences)**

Given the premise of Conjecture 1, for consecutive zeros $\rho_n$ and $\rho_{n-1}$ on the critical line, the difference between their ordinates $\gamma_{n-1}$ and $\gamma_n$, diminishes as $n$ grows.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \gamma_{n} - \gamma_{n-1} = 0$

**Conjecture 3 (Zero simplicity)**

Incorporating the core idea, the cycle limit imposed by the invariant topology suggests that the maximal multiplicity of a multiple zero is 1; i.e., all zeros are simple.

**Conjecture 4 (Ramanujan)**

Let $ab= \pi$. If Conjecture 1 holds, the following Ramanujan elliptic relation might work:

\begin{align}
& \sqrt{a} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} e^{-\left(\frac{a}{n} \right)^2} - \sqrt{b} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} e^{-\left(\frac{b}{n} \right)^2} \\[8pt]
= {} &  -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b}} \sum b^\rho \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} \rho\right)}{\zeta'(\rho)}
\end{align}

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this.  Are $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ the real and imaginary parts of $\zeta(s)$?  What does '$\sigma$ tends to the real part of all the non-trivial zeros' mean?

Comment: As usual, sigma and t are the real and imaginary parts of the zeta function. I assume that the real part of the zeta function, is restricted to the zeros in and to the right of the critical line, as t tends to infinity. $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ are harmonic functions.

Comment: When the zeta function is complex, $f$ and $g$ are, respectively, the real and imaginary part of this complex number.

Comment: not sure that I understand what is Conjecture $1$; $\zeta=f+ig$ then where do you claim that $|f(s)|-|g(s)| \to 0$? I do not think that is true if $s=1/2+it$ and $t \to \infty$ while if you claim this only for $t_n \sim \gamma_n$ the ordinates of zero, that seems to be trivially true as both $f,g$ are zero near $1/2+i\gamma_n$

Comment: Conjecture 1 is that the diference $|f(s)| - |g(s)|$ tends to zero when $s = \lambda_n +it$, where $\rho_n = \lambda_n + i\gamma_n$ runs through all the zero's of the zeta function on the critical strip, and $t$ tends to infinity(not to $\gamma_n$). I do not assume RH.

Conrad: are you sure this is false? Has it been proven? My intention is to see if by assuming conjecture 1, the finer shades of the imaginary behaviour of $\zeta(s)$ might be illuminated...

Best

Comment: basically, you claim then that $|f(1/2+it)|-|g(1/2+it)| \to 0, t\to \infty$  (since for sure we know there are zeroes on the critical line); that cannot be true since we know that $Z(t)=(f(1/2+it)+ig(1/2+it)(cos \theta (t)+i\sin \theta (t)$ is real so if $f(t)=f(1/2+it)$ etc $f(t)\sin \theta(t)+g(t)\cos \theta(t)=0$ and$\theta(t)=\frac{t}{2}(\log t/(2\pi))-t/2-\pi/8+O(1/t)$; hence if $|f(t)|-|g(t)| \to 0$ you would need $|f(t)|(1-|\tan \theta (t)|) \to 0$; but $|f(t)|, |g(t)|$ are quite large on a big chunk of the critical 'ine by Selberg limit theorem and $\theta$ is far from constant

Comment: Conrad. Thank you for the bright response. A few comments.

It seems to me that you are assuming that $|\zeta(s)|$ is bounded near the critical line, which is a much weaker assumptiom than RH(RH implies a bound, but not viceversa).

If, as we come infinitessimally close to the critical line(or to the real part of a zero), $|\zeta(s)|$ becomes unbounded, then it is perfectly possible that the product 

$|f(t)|(1 -|\tan\theta(t)|$

might tend to zero, as t tends to infinity, even if we assume $\lambda_n$ to be fixed.

Comment: $\zeta$ is highly unbounded near and on the critical line (on big chunks on the critical line we know specific lower bounds by Selberg limit theorem) and so are $f,g$; on the other hand $\theta$ is fairly regular so for $ |f(t)|(1 -|\tan\theta(t)| \to 0$ we would need at the minimum $(1 -|\tan\theta(t))) \to 0$ on these chunks and that is clearly not the case by the asymptotic formula for $\theta$

Comment: for example for large enough $T$ on pretty much half the interval (measure wise) $[T, 2T]$ one has $|\zeta(1/2+it)| \ge e^{((\log log T)/2)^{49/100}}$ (and of course pretty much on the other half we have  $|\zeta(1/2+it)| \le e^{-((\log log T)/2)^{49/100}}$)

Comment: While this is evidence against conjecture 1, it is far from a refutation. 

We know that $1 -|\tan\theta(t)|$ does not tend to zero on a big chunk of the critical line, where $|\zeta(s)|$ is bounded by the central limit theorem, and yet $1 -|\tan\theta(t)|$ might end up becoming zero as $t$ tends to infinity.

Comment: There is stronger evidence against my conjecture: Karatsuba showed that certain bounds on $|\zeta(s)|$ in infinitessimally short intervals near the crirical line, imply bounds on the multiplicity of zeros. This seems to show that as a function of $t$, the diference 

$|f(\lambda_n + it)| - |g(\lambda_n + it)|$

would not merge into a constant for infinite t: but it is still far from a refutation, since the multiplicity is merely bounded by a multiple of log $t$, and hence is free to force the difference to vanish, as $t$ grows.

Comment: Conjecture 2 is known unconditionally, due to Littlewood.  This is Theorem 9.11 in Titchmarsh.

Comment: By tightening the bounds on $S(t)$ and $S_1(t)$, you could prove conjecture 2 directly. But this bounds are still a mystery...